# How do you set the base address of your API without hardcoding it?

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpclientfactory, ihttpclientfactory

I'm using HttpClientFactory to make API calls in a client application.
The API and the client app are both in the same Visual Studio solution. When executing my solution both apps are running on localhost on different ports. When creating an HttpClient instance I set the baseaddress uri like this `httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7854");`.

With **"not hardcoding it"** I mean: I don't want to put the Uri in any code or config or json file or Azure Key Vault or whatever.

I want to avoid hardcoding the address and find an easier way since both Apps are in the same solution. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration

Comment: you could store the api address in a json file and take it from there

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the address in code or config files or Azure Key Vault..., as the environments might change in the future. The projects will surelly stay in the same solution.

Comment: Even if both projects running on the same machine you have at least to configure the port on which your API is running and this information must be configured on both sides, the API server and the client. So you have to hard-code it somewhere. The most _dynamic_ place I could think of would be a command line parameter or an environment variable, but it has to be defined.

Comment: No Json file. No Key vault. No config file. Soooo make a separate .netstandard project that has the HttpClient. Then use that project in both apps?

Comment: Awkward idea: If both running on the same machine the server could start first and pick a _random_ free port for listening. Then it could open a named pipe with a `hardcoded name` and the client could read through the named pipe the choosen port.

Comment: `as the environments might change in the future` - but configs can be deployed to every environment. Maybe I don't get your point..? Same for environment variables - pretty much every OS used for servers/api can read from environment. Docker too ... Why are config-files bothering you so much?

Comment: I know you can put the uri in config files it's just I'm curious on finding a different method and avoid changing it everytime the API is deployed somewhere online...

Comment: @nilsK I don't want to put the api address into config files

Comment: Last thing that comes to my mind ... if you have any form of automated deployment system, you probably can set the variable there. E.g. with [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) you configure a server (tentacle) and each of them has a bunch of parameters, customs too. During deployment, Octopus replaces placeholder in your config files with parameters you set in Octpus' backend. There are different systems, thats just the one i used recently. But at some point you have to do the configuration manually, e.g. entering a new IP somewhere.